# How to import UML diagram file into draw.io

Tags: uml, plantuml, draw.io

Is it possible to convert database diagram exported from DataGrip in *.uml format into diagram suported in draw.io? Or is it possible to convert it into PlantUML somehow -> this is also loadable into draw.io..

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: The [documentation of DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/fr-fr/datagrip/features/importexport.html) speaks about export in csv, json, xml or **d**ml, not **u**ml, are you sure you do not confuse ?

Comment: I didn't mean data export but export of database schema. This is possible to be exported into uml when you generate diagram and there is an option to export such a diagram into UML. See attached image..

Comment: but what is the content ? a UML diagram is a 'picture' showing a part of the model, a 'picture' cannot be used wihout the corresponding data in the model. Is your file follow xmi or diagram interchange ? Note  draw.io and PlantUML  aren't UML tool but only drawing tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can import any file type to drawio, however, the *.uml diagram will not properly translate to a drawio diagram, only table names will appear. It is not possible to import/convert a *.uml into PlantUML.